# Python threadpool hangs after MacBook lid shut

Tags: python, macos

When using `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` I get a silent error where the existing threadpool does not restart (Python 3.6.5, macOS 10.15.4). An example similar to my use case:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import requests
import time

def child_process(url):
   response = requests.get(url)
   time.sleep(2)
   return response.text


def main():
   counter = 0
   with ThreadPoolExecutor(10) as pool:
      while True:
         args = ['https://www.google.com' for _ in range(10)]
         results = pool.map(child_process, args)
         [i for i in results]
         counter += 1
         print(f'{counter}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

produces:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
```

where the program is now hung at 12 after shutting the lid of my MacBook (assuming it's in a sleep or power nap state) and reopening.

Has anyone else experienced this issue? Is there a way to make sure the program safely restarts?

Comment: Can you repeat this example without using a URL get, and/or also avoid the sleep(.) function?